# cannot install ckan properly with solr

Tags: solr, ckan

I have installed ckan using source, but could not setup solr properly using jetty as described in the oficcial installation guide, so i installed solr-5.0.0 seperately.

The solr runs ok, and I have set up the development.ini file properly, but when I connect to ckan, I get among others the error:

> "ERROR [ckan.lib.search.common] HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found" .

Even when I set `"ckan.simple_search = 1"` and comment out the `solr_url`, in the development.ini, the same error appears, and it seems like it's trying to connect with solr.

In both cases the ckan site appears , but it has the error:

> Server Error
>
> An internal server error occurred

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To fix the error, I appended the name of my core to the solr_url variable.

In my case, I named my core ckan.

So my solr_url variable was similar to:

http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan

This allowed me to initialize the database as per the CKAN installation instructions without getting the 404 error you describe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem with my installation was that in the ckan configuration file, when entering the solr url, it had a backslash in the end and it shouldn't.